# Ios app getting strange error in metal shader code

Tags: c++, ios, metal-performance-shaders

Ios app hangs on with a strange error in metal shader code, C++

When I comment the function getPixelOnTop --> The app works fine:

```cpp
if( (checkSelectablePixel || checkNext) && isInnerRect(iRect, rect) ){
//            pixel2 = getPixelOnTop(nextX, nextY,
//                                   p2.index,
//                                   pixels,
//                                   pixelCount,
//                                   rect,
//                                   status,
//                                   checkNext,
//                                   checkInnerRect,
//                                   removedColor);
        }
```

But, if I bound it by condition false, it hangs on!!!

```cpp
if( (checkSelectablePixel || checkNext) && isInnerRect(iRect, rect) ){
    if(false){
            pixel2 = getPixelOnTop(nextX, nextY,
                                   p2.index,
                                   pixels,
                                   pixelCount,
                                   rect,
                                   status,
                                   checkNext,
                                   checkInnerRect,
                                   removedColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I don't know what happened" - Did you check your version control system to see what changes were made? That's usually how one finds out "what happened" between working and broken versions of code.

Comment: My Xcode version is 11 - beta4, my app using Metal. And I stuck on Metal.
The app works fine in simulator, but my device hangs on: 6th ipad, 9.7inch.